# Is hash calculated before/after compression?

Tags: hashing, compression

I had a question regarding compression and calculation of checksum/hash of data.

I would like to know if checksum has to be calculated before or after the compression of  data before transmission. Could someone please explain this so that I can get a better understanding of it?

Comment: I think you're going to have to bring your question down a notch or two -- you're speaking all in theory. Are you talking about OSI or TCPIP checksums for a network stack? Are you talking about some particular compression algorithm?

Comment: I am interested in calculating my own checksum and appending it to the compressed data before sending it to the destination. I want to know if this checksum should be calculated before or after compression of the data?

Comment: Why are you doing this when network protocols like TCP/IP guarantee that you don't have fragmented data?  (The checksum is already built in to the network stack).  That's why I asked about bringing the question down a notch.  What network stack are you using?  What protocol are you using?  It seems likely you're [wasting your time](http://sourcemaking.com/antipatterns/reinvent-the-wheel) if you're writing something beyond really low-level (like physical/data-link layer) code.

Comment: @JoeRounceville I agree with most of your points, the file transfer is adequately checksummed at the transmission layer. There is one capability that adding a whole file checksum to the cleartext allows: you can confirm at a time after the transmission that the file matches its checksum. Why one would would want a homebrew checksum when there's a family of them out there for free is beyond me.

Comment: @msw:  true enough, but even then you just move up the stack a bit and find a guaranteed delivery messaging library that will handle that for you (a la MSMQ or JMS).  Unless I was literally writing such a messaging library myself, I'd never do my own checksums -- there are too many ways to screw it up, plus it's retreading old tires.

Answer (score 5):

Normally, a hash is calculated before compression. That way, the receiver can verify the hash *after* decompression, which verifies not only the data transmission but also the compression and decompression implementations.

Comment: Yes, strike that. I figured out what was really bugging me: Many checksums are calculated over arbitrary payload which may very well be compressed (e.g., TCP, many network protocols building on TCP, torrents, Ethernet frames, IPv4). To checksum the uncompressed data, the part doing the checksum has to know about the compression taking place.

Comment: That's true. It depends on the details of each protocol, certainly. If the compression is done at a higher level than the protocol (such as HTTP gzip compression over TCP), then the TCP checksum has no knowledge of the HTTP gzip compression in the TCP payload, and it certainly isn't possible to checksum the uncompressed data at the TCP level.

Answer (score 1):

This sounds similar to encryption and MAC order. The preferred approach in that setting is to encrypt and then add the MAC. There is no reason not to follow the same order in this case. You should compress and then add the checksum/hash. That way the integrity of the compressed payload can be checked before doing any kind of decompression. If you add the checksum/hash and then compress then you force the client to decompress to check the integrity of the payload whereas with compress-then-checksum approach you save the client the trouble of decompression if the integrity of the payload is compromised. Here's the link about encryption and MAC order: https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/202/should-we-mac-then-encrypt-or-encrypt-then-mac.